# Can we pass a public IP address to ng serve?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and may be this is a very basic question,
I have deployed a CentOS VM on Google cloud platform to use it as my sandbox for angular learning.
I am trying to run "ng serve -host " and getting below error,
*An unhandled exception occurred: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available IP:4200.*

Also, I checked the firewall status of my VM and its inactive

I went through the official documentation of angular cli but could not find any details about the kind of IP addresses we can pass with -host option.

On few articles on web found few examples with local IP addresses <10.x.x.x> but none with public IP address.

Can someone please help me to understand if public IPs are supported with ng serve or am I missing here anything ?

Thanks,
Abhijit.

Comment: You mean you are trying to allow access outside the localhost ?

Comment: ng serve is meant for local debugging sessions, not for serving the app to the public. You should use a real web server setup.

Comment: As long as you have deployed the app on your server you can access it through the server's IP address you can make the server IP public or just private. Though it might be a good idea to just have a domain name for the app. When you are deploying your angular app you also need to build the files which usually end up in dist folder then use  something like NGINX to serve the dist folder.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
The reason i am trying to use public IP address with ng serve is, i am using the GCP VM for angular development and i am modiyfing the code files from my laptop through winscp tool, so when i make any changes i want to see the pages on my local browser. 
one more solution to this i can do is use VNC viewer to connect to the CentOS VM GUI and then access the angular app on the local browser. 
But wanted to check if i can use public IP of GCP VM with ng serve.

Answer (score 0):

To expose ng serve to public use

ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check